# How can I groupby a date range and and sum up dates that fall within the range?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using pandas dataframe and matplotlib to create a time series plot.

I have some dates within my dataframe that I need to group by a weekly frequency. I already tried to groupby(dt.week).count(), however my dates span over multiple years and the ticks don't show anything other than the number of the week (1-52).

```
ct_weekly_freq = df2['authorTimestamp'].groupby(df2['authorTimestamp'].dt.week).count().plot(kind='line')
plt.show()
```

This would be an alright plot if it wasn't for the fact that it involves multiple years. I would like to figure out how to have it sum up the dates that fall within a weekly frequency from the starting date and have the tick marks show the date as well.

Comment: Resample your data at '1W' frequency.